# Grid item `Link` not centering as expected

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

This is a TypeScript React project using Material UI.
I want to center the Link component with the text `"Send emails to new applicants →"` like this [reproduction here](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-leakey-nfkf6?file=/src/App.js).

However, in my local codebase, the same code **breaks** centering like below.

[image]

I also realized a weird behavior.
For the property of `Grid` item element around my `Link` component,

Centering **breaks** when:
`<Grid item xs={12}>`

Centering **works** when: `<Grid item>`

This must mean another part of my code is preventing this item from centering.

So I have checked the followings,

1. The stylesheet of my current page has nothing related to layout.
2. `<WrapperPage>` does not contain any style

**But where else in the code should I check?** Any recommened approach?

This is a TypeScript React project using Material UI.
The `Link` component comes from Material UI,
and the `RouterLink` comes from React Router.

The actual code is like this.

`SubmittedApplications.tsx`

```
import { Box, Card, Grid, Typography, Link } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
...
    <WrapperPage>
      <Grid container justifyContent="center" spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Typography variant="h3" align="center">
            Submitted Applications
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Link
            component={RouterLink}
            to="/sendemail"
            variant="h5"
            align="center"
          >
            Send emails to new applicants →
          </Link>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    ...
    </WrapperPage>
```

Edit1: The Link component of Codesandbox and local have similar properties...[image]

Edit2: Computed screenshot
[image]

Edit3: Parent Grid element Comparison
[image]

Comment: Between the codesandbox where it works as expected and your local build, examine the DOM in the dev tools, specifically the computed style of that element(and maybe parent elements) to see what is eventually different.

Comment: @DrewReese They are the same unfortunately... just added the screenshot

Comment: Those aren't the same though, they definitely aren't identical. Click into the "Computed" tab so you can see ***all*** the CSS rules agains the element and then you can see where it's inherited from.

Comment: @DrewReese Just added "Computed" properties for both. I do see the differences ike `box-sizing` but disabling it does not do anything, so I do not understand which part is significant or relevant ;(

Comment: @DrewReese On my local, I realized that disabling `text-align: center` inside `.MuiTypography-alignCenter` causes all text to go left-aligned, but no effect on codesandbox. Perhaps here..?

Comment: Ok, if the link elements are fairly similar, try going up the DOM tree, check the parents, and so on. Re "text-align: center", perhaps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237348/discussion-between-leonard-and-drew-reese).